# UnitTest on method accessing specific resource file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am trying to write a unit test for a public method A(), which is calling another method B() that is accessing a specific resx file, doing something with its members according to its input parameter and returning sth. My question is is there a standard procedure for when I want to test A(), but don't want want to statically or manually modify the resx file for my testing purposes?

Can I write a method that programatically modifies the resx file before I run the actual test? I should note that I am quite unfamiliar with the concept of dependency injection, although I am guessing that the solution for this issue might go in that direction.

Have a look at my code structure

THX yall!!!

```
public class ClassA {
    void MethodA<T>() {
        DoSomething(ClassB.MethodB<T>());
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    IEnumerable<string>MethodB<T>() {
        foreach(var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))){
            DoSomething(ResxFileA.GetResource(v));
        }
        return IEnumerable<string>;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass {
    Enum MockEnum { /*...*/ }

    [TestMethod]
    TestMethod {
        ClassA.MethodA<MockEnum>();
        Assert.AreEqual(/*...*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question how does the `DoSomething()` function looks like? Guessing its something `static`... Although I would specifically put that `DoSomething()` call behind an `interface` that you could inject to your classes constructor. And then you could mock it in your tests.

Comment: Well the point is that I don't want to alter my pre-existent code. I created the ClassA.MethodA() and now I want to test it, but ultimately it accesses the resx file according to the names of an enum, meaning the enum names correspond with the resx members. When I create a mock enum I don't have the corresponding members in the resx file. My whole problem is, how do I get them there? Or can I exchange the whole resx file (which is hardcoded in ClassB.MethodB)?

Comment: That sounds more like to an integration test. However to me seeing your code tells me that I would just modify the existing codebase and setup the mocks behaviour as per described.